# Как через echo вывести в файл слово SERVICE?

Tags: windows, oracle, bat

Пытаюсь силами `bat` файла создать файл инициализации для БД Oracle.
Минимальный пример моего файла:

```
@echo off
SET ORACLE_SID=SID1
IF 1==1 (
echo *.dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=%ORACLE_SID%2XDB)' >>D:\1.TXT
)
```

Получаю ошибку:

> (SERVICE was unexpected at this time.

Ругается на слово SERVICE. Как можно заставить работать этот вывод?

Из забавного, если убрать `IF`, то ошибок нет.

Пробовал экранировать слово символом `^`, однако к успеху это не привело

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Пробовал экранировать слово символом ^, однако к успеху это не привело

Экранировать символом `^` нужно закрывающие скобки, иначе они воспринимаются как завершение `IF`, что и приводит к ошибке (неожиданный контент после `IF`).

```
@echo off
SET ORACLE_SID=SID1
IF 1==1 (
echo *.dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP^) (SERVICE=%ORACLE_SID%2XDB^)' >>D:\1.TXT
)
```

Comment: Ну и парсер, однако) строковый литерал вообще ничего не решает? =)

Comment: @vp_arth Парсер конечно тот еще, но нет там строкового литерала, это все аргумент `echo` (например кавычку можно и не закрывать). Можно обернуть его в двойные кавычки, это решит проблему, но кавычки тоже будут выведены в файл. С этим тоже можно бороться, но мне лень :)

Comment: Внезапное поведение, такого я не ожидал.

Comment: @Viktorov Никто не ожидает и̶с̶п̶а̶н̶с̶к̶у̶ю̶ и̶н̶к̶в̶и̶з̶и̶ц̶и̶ю̶  поведение batch-файла :) Если это новый скрипт, попробуйте написать его на Powershell. Он несколько более предсказуем.